# exterior measure: is $m^*(O\backslash E)=m^*(O)-m^*(E)$

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose $E$ not measurable and $O\supset E$ an open set. Do we have
$$m^*(O\backslash E)=m^*(O)-m^*(E) \ ?$$
and if not and if $E$ is mesurable, do we have the equality ?

To me it would be logic that we always have the equality, but I often make mistakes, that's why I'm asking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can partition $(0, 1) = E \sqcup F$ such that $m^{\star}(E) = m^{\star}(F) = 1$. Now if $O = (0, 1)$, then $1 = m^{\star}(F) = m^{\star}(O \backslash E) \neq m^{\star}(O) - m^{\star}(E) = 1 - 1 = 0$.

If $E$ is measurable, then by additivity of measure, $m(O) = m(E) \cup m(O \backslash E)$. So if $m(E) < \infty$, $m(O \backslash E) = m(O) - m(E)$.